# Strange pronunciation of 非常

Tags: pronunciation, taiwan

I listen to podcasts from Taiwan for listening practice and I think I hear the word 非常 [fēichánɡ] often pronounced like 飛揚 [fēiyánɡ] in them. Am I hearing it right or am I confusing it with some other word? If the word is indeed pronounced that way sometimes (perhaps in casual speech?), is it a common phenomenon or a regional thing?

Comment: Any links to examples?

Comment: Similar to the Cantonese, Some of the Taiwanese people have a heavy local accent because the Taiwanese (閩南語) lacking certain sounds that involve controlling the muscle of the tongue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. I like your use of `飛揚` here. While it is comical or cultural to use an otherwise unrelated word to signify an [elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taiwanese_Mandarin#Elision) – e.g., consider `醬子` in place of `這樣子` in Taiwanese Mandarin internet slang – if you are looking for an answer of more academic rigour, IPA should be used, not Chinese characters or *pinyin*. (Because after elision, what you spell may not always be orthographic.)
2. In Taiwanese Mandarin, [Chung (2006:77)](http://www.concentric-linguistics.url.tw/upload/articlesfs161402111125124738.pdf) notices function words (虛詞) tend to get deemphasised via elision. `非常` is an intensifier (somewhat functional), so the following elision can be observed:

   `非常 fēi cháng /feɪ˥˥ ʈʂʰɑŋ˧˥/ → [feɪ˥˥ ɑŋ˧˥] or [feɪ˥˥ hɑŋ˧˥]`

   Notice how usually the initial of the second syllable tends to get dropped in quick speech.

   Your including a voiced palatal approximant `[j]` between the two syllables (i.e., `[feɪ˥˥ jɑŋ˧˥]`, which just so happens to be the pronunciation of `飛揚 fēiyáng`) is permissible, perhaps serving as a 'glide' between `ɪ` and `ɑ`.
3. The following is an example where there are no Chinese characters or *pinyin* that can properly describe the elision of `今天`:

   `今天 jīn tiān /tɕɪn˥˥ tʰjɛn˥˥/ → [tɕɪ‿ɛn˥˥]`

   While there is `雞 jī /tɕi˥˥/`, when pronouncing *i* in the *pinyin* *ji*, your mouth is more closed and your tongue is more front than when pronouncing *i* in *jin*. This subtlety can only be reflected using IPA. Whereas obviously there is no `/ɛn/` as a syllable in Mandarin.

**References**

Chung, Karen Steffen. "Contraction and Backgrounding in Taiwan Mandarin." Concentric: Studies in Linguistics, vol. 32.1, 2006, pp. 69-88.

Comment: Thank+1. I wasn’t particularly looking for an answer of academic rigor, but I can understand your explanation. I have noticed the people who pronounce 非常 like that also tend to pronounce 他/她/它 [tʰɑ] like [hɑ]. I guess it’s another symptom of the same phenomenon.